# Cannot reload page while Chrome devtools debugger paused in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am debugging a React app made with create-react-app.

Reloading while paused on a breakpoint causes the page to stall.  The page goes blank and will not reload; the tab can't be immediately closed.  The dead tab appears to be trying to reload (spinner appears), but never reloads.  I have to open the page in a new tab.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026560/chrome-javascript-debugger-when-paused-wont-reload-page?rq=1 You have to unpause and then reload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that I **must** allow the debugger to continue past all breakpoints before reloading the page.  Alternative: deactivate all breakpoints, then click resume.  This prevents the page from stalling (and then requiring the tab to be killed and reopened).

Comment: Yikes.. still going on in chromium now. It comes across as a really bad bug. Very concerning for devs who may be wondering if there could be a production issue, when in fact it's a strange chromium "quirk"